# Why the principal (money) is called Keren?

Tags: words, money, etymology

In all kinds of monetary transactions, the main part is called Keren or for the reward for Mitzvot as in Kesubos 3,9:

> "הָאוֹמֵר גָּנַבְתִּי וְטָבַחְתִּי וּמָכָרְתִּי, **מְשַׁלֵּם אֶת הַקֶּרֶן** עַל פִּי עַצְמוֹ, וְאֵינוֹ מְשַׁלֵּם תַּשְׁלוּמֵי כֶפֶל וְתַשְׁלוּמֵי אַרְבָּעָה וַחֲמִשָּׁה."

or Peah 1,1:

> "אלו דברים שאדם אוכל פירותיהן בעולם הזה **והקרן קיימת לו** לעולם הבא."

**Why is it called Keren and where's the first usage of that word in that meaning (is there a Pasuk or it's all Rabbinical)?**

*(I'm not sure about the title, feel free to edit.)*

Comment: What would *you* like it to be called instead?

Comment: Answer here:
https://www.safa-ivrit.org/writers/etsion/keren.php
In short, there are the no real answers, only some educated guesses.

Answer (score 1):

According to [קרן השור וקרן ממון](https://www.safa-ivrit.org/writers/etsion/keren.php) (thanks to Nbubis) the use of the word קרן for the principal stems from [Vaikra 5, 24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.5.24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) "**וְשִׁלַּם אֹתוֹ בְּרֹאשׁוֹ** וַחֲמִשִׁתָיו יֹסֵף עָלָיו", lit. "pays off his head", where the word "head" was allegedly replaced with "horn" because a person's property was measured by his cattle.

### קרן כראש ממון

> נחזור לשאלה שבה פתחנו – האם יש קשר בין הקרן הבולטת לבין הקרן הכספית? המילה קרן במשמע 'סכום הכסף העיקרי' נתחדשה בלשון חז"ל. במשנה רווחת משמעות זו. כך למשל במסכת תרומות (פרק ו): "האוכל תרומה שוגג, משלם קרן וחומש". כך גם במשנה הפותחת את מסכת פאה, שנוהגים לאומרה לאחר ברכות התורה בבקרים: "אלו דברים שאדם אוכל פירותיהן בעולם הזה והקרן קיימת לו לעולם הבא...".
>
> עוד לפני המשנה, אנו פוגשים את המילה בתרגום הארמי הארצישראלי לתורה (ניאופיטי). בפרשת ויקרא מלמדת התורה את דינו של מי שכיחש בממון ונשבע לשקר: "נֶפֶשׁ כִּי תֶחֱטָא וּמָעֲלָה מַעַל בה' וְכִחֵשׁ בַּעֲמִיתוֹ... וְשִׁלַּם אֹתוֹ בְּרֹאשׁוֹ וַחֲמִשִׁתָיו יֹסֵף עָלָיו". המילים האחרונות בפסוק מתורגמות כך: "וישלם יתה בקרנא וחומשוי יוסף עלוי". המילה 'בראשו', שמובנה התשלום הראשי, שווי הממון המקורי, מיתרגמת למילה "קרן" (וכן פירש רש"י שם: "בראשו - הוא הקרן, ראש הממון").
>
> על פי זה, ייתכן לומר שאמנם מקור הקרן הכספית בקרן הממשית, כתחליף למילה ראש. ברשימה קודמת הזכרנו שבעולם העתיק הונו של אדם נמדד לפי מספר ראשי הבהמות שהחזיק, ולפיכך - כשם שניתן לומר ראש ולהתכוון לבהמה כולה, כך גם ניתן לומר 'קרן' באותה משמעות (ונזכיר כאן גם את דיוננו לפני שבועות מספר במילה 'פרסה' ככינוי לבהמה כולה). בערבית, אגב, עד היום הקרן הכספית נקראת רַאס מַאל, היינו 'ראש ממון'.
>
> אפשרות אחרת להסבר המילה קרן הביא פרופ' נפתלי הרץ טור-סיני, שהשלים את מלאכת מילונו של אליעזר בן יהודה. לפי דבריו הקרן במובן סכום כסף כלל אינה קשורה לקרן שבראש, אלא דווקא למילה 'גורן', שמובנה ערמת תבואה (וסָמַך דבריו במילה אכדית מקבילה).
>
> על כל פנים, המילה קרן שמובנה 'סכום כסף' הפכה בעברית המתחדשת גם לכינוי לאגודה האוספת כספים למען עניין כלשהו (כגון 'הקרן הקיימת לישראל', שנטלה את שמה מהמשנה בפאה שנזכרה לעיל) - ומכאן התרחבה גם לאגודה כללית, שפעילותה אינה קשורה דווקא לאיסוף כספים (למשל: הקרן להכוונת חיילים משוחררים במשרד הביטחון).